# Using Hangfire, how can I configure a web app to enqueue with BackgroundJobClient.Create without starting an in process server?

Tags: .net, .net-core, hangfire

Our web app enqueues jobs using `BackgroundJobClient.Create`, but we want to process all jobs in a separate Windows service rather than in our web app. If our web app starts without calling `builder.UseHangfireServer`, creating new jobs throws the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. 
You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.
```

It appears that the `AddHangfire(options => ...UseSqlServerStorage(...)` lambda does not run until `UseHangfireServer` gets called. As a workaround, we can configure our web app to listen to queues named after some GUID, but that seems like a waste of resources for the web app which might run multiple instances in a web farm.

Is there any way to configure a Hangfire client without starting a Hangfire server in the same process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to configure a Hangfire client without starting a
>   Hangfire server in the same process ?

Yes, as far as I know, for the client module, you just need to create your `BackgroundJobClient` like this :

```
IBackgroundJobClient client = new BackgroundJobClient(new SqlServerStorage(yourConnectionString)) ;
// or any overload of the SqlServerStorage constructor.
```

Comment: Tried it and verified it works. Taking it one step further, it is a good idea to inject BackgroundJobClient as `IBackgroundJobClient` with the following: 

    `services.AddTransient<IBackgroundJobClient>(_ =>
        new BackgroundJobClient(new SqlServerStorage(hfConnString, storageOptions)));`